# Getting Launchd to repeatedly run a script without waiting for previous launch to finish in OSX

Tags: macos, launchd, launchdagent

Let's say I have the script below

```
#! /bin/bash
sleep 300
dt=$(date '+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
echo $dt >> /foo/bar/test.txt
```

When I set up a launchagent to trigger this script every 2 minutes... launchd will wait for the script to finish before triggering it again.  So instead of the date every 2 minutes (after a 300 second sleep) I get it every 5 minutes or more.  Is there a way for launchd to launch the script every 2 minutes, regardless of whether it has completed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to have the launch agent run the script in the background, something like this:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
      <string>/bin/bash</string>
      <string>-c</string>
      <string>/path/to/script &</string>

</array>
<key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
<true/>
```

Notes: If you need to pass any arguments to your script, include them in the same `<string>` as the script path, delimited by spaces (rather than as separate `<string>`s, like you normally would in the launch daemon file). The `AbandonProcessGroup` key is needed to prevent launchd from "helpfully" killing any leftover subprocesses (like your actual script) when what it thinks of as the daemon process exits.

Comment: I just tested this on my theoretical script and it didn't work entirely.  However, I added a "trigger" script and directed your plist to that.  That script executed the test.sh and ended with a `&`.  Now I am getting log entries every 2 minutes as desired.  Not sure if there is a more elegant way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is *almost* perfect--props to him.

The reason arlovande ran into issues was that the " &" part wasn't properly LaunchDaemon-ified. Anytime a space would happen, a new entry is needed under `<array>`

Therefore:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/bin/bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>/path/to/script</string>
    <string>&</string>
</array>
<key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
<true/>
```